# 'tee off on someone' or 'tee off someone'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

This is from the podcast [Stuff You Should Know](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-stuff-you-should-know-26940277/episode/whats-nato-all-about-94894577/).

> Josh: Okay. So and they, that happened basically in real life. It was
> such a close resemblance to that I remember a reporter asking Bill
> Clinton like “Have you ever seen the movie *Wag the Dog*?” Because it
> like the Balkan NATO missions started like right as the Monica
> Lewinsky scandal was heating up.
>
> Chuck: And he said “It depends on what your definition of scene is…
>
> Josh:  That’s right. I mean we’re gonna be able to **tee off on** that
> guy forever huh.

Josh seems to have used the phrase 'tee off' meaning 'to make someone annoyed' as defined in [*The Free Dictionary*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tee+off).

But 'tee off on' is defined as 'to speak about (someone or something) in an angry way' in *[Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tee%20off%20on%20%28someone%20or%20something%29)*.

So I think 'on' should be omitted in the above context.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you made a mistake? Both your cited dictionaries use "tee off **on**" and so does your quote. Why do you think the idiom is wrong? I would recommend you default to Websters for American English, it is a recognised authority, the free dictionary is like Wikipedia, it can be wrong.

Comment: @Astralbee https://www.collinsdictionary.com/ko/dictionary/english/tee-off

Comment: @Astralbee https://www.lexico.com/definition/tee_off

Comment: @DialFrost  I wonder whether Josh means they can annoy Bill Clinton by parodying his Grand Jury testimony or they are mad at his perjury.

Comment: For what it's worth, I, a native US English speaker, have never heard "tee off on" used the way that Webster's defines it.  I wonder if Josh was trying to make some metaphor about using this as a starting point, like how a golfer starts by teeing off.

Comment: @stangdon I thought Chuck is parodying the Bill Clinton's famous saying in Grand Jury testimony, that is, "It depends on what the meaning of the word 'is' is", which Josh think can annoy Bill Clinton. So I find just 'tee off someone' is appropriate phrase meaning 'make someone angry or annoyed.'.

Comment: @SEProfile  Right, I understand what the parody is, but it's not clear to me whether Josh thinks he's annoying Bill Clinton with this, and if he is, why he would say "tee off **on**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong, the "on" should be there.

[Example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tee%20off%20on%20%28someone%20or%20something%29) of "tee off on something/someone".